# '70s era movie about pandemic and extermination system

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv

I watched a movie on late-night television in the 90s. It may have been from the 70s or 80s. It had a rather stark and gritty feel to it.

The plot was that there was an AIDS-like infectious disease. The government's response was to set up camps and a secret extermination program. If you test positive (everyone has an ID for this), you are taken to the facility where you are clamped to a column and an automated system, with a conveyor belt, admits you.

I think there was a scene where one of the staff tested positive and was dragged out. One of the programmers at the facility finds out something (possibly the government has a cure and the director uses the system to eliminate undesirables) and sets up the system so that the programs to run it are on his keycard and not on the machine.

When he leaves, he takes the keycard with him and the system shuts down. The workers try to reactivate it, to no avail. When he returns, and clears out the facility, he puts the card back in and the system comes to life. He programs the system so that the director, without whom the system will collapse, registers a false positive and he is sent in protesting, to be killed by his own program. He is alone on the lot and they watch him go in.

I've looked at IMDb and Wikipedia, but haven't come up with anything.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I searched IMBD for likely matches. I found [Quarantine (1989)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0245378/?ref_=kw_li_tt)

I found a copy online and looked at the end. It certainly matches your description.

Here's the trailer.

Comment: Thanks for finding this. I didn't see it on IMDb, guess I was looking at the wrong things.